# leetcode: sort an array of n objects with k different colors

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

My output is [1, 2, 2, 4, 3], not right. It should be [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]. But I can't find the error in my code. Could anyone help me find out the error of algorithm ? Thank you.
My entire code is copied below. It can be implemented.

Question:

Given an array of n objects with k different colors (numbered from 1 to k), sort them so that objects of the same color are adjacent, with the colors in the order 1, 2, ... k.

Example:
Given colors=[3, 2, 2, 1, 4], k=4, your code should sort colors in-place to [1, 2, 2, 3, 4].

Requirements:
A rather straight forward solution is a two-pass algorithm using counting sort. That will cost O(k) extra memory. Can you do it without using extra memory?

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortColorsII {
   public static void sortColors2(int[] colors, int k) {  
    int count = 0;  
    int start = 0;  
    int end = colors.length-1;  
    while (count <= k) {  
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;  
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;  

        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {  
            min = Math.min(min, colors[i]);  
            max = Math.max(max, colors[i]);  
        }  
        int left = start;  
        int right = end;  
        int cur = left;  
        while(cur <= right) {  
            if (colors[cur] == min) {  
                swap(left, cur, colors);  
                cur++;  
                left++;  
            } else if(colors[cur] == max) {  
                swap(cur, right, colors);  
                right--;  
            } else {  
                cur++; 
            }  
        }  
        count += 2;  
        start = left;  
        end = right;  
    }  
}  

private static void swap(int left, int right, int[] colors) {  
    int tmp = colors[left];  
    colors[left] = colors[right];  
    colors[right] = tmp;  
} 
   public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] colors = new int[]{3, 2, 2, 1, 4};
    int k = 4;
    sortColors2(colors,  k);
    String res = Arrays.toString(colors);
    System.out.println(res);
   }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a slightly modified selection sort. Granted, it uses less memory but the complexity is O(n * k). You'd probably be better off just using QuickSort.

Comment: Thank you ,I will try it.@Pham Trung

Answer (score 1):

Your minimum/maximum search excludes the last element. Use an inclusive upper bound:

```
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you Nico. How careless I am!

Comment: @StevenWang Remember to accept answers (by clicking the check mark next to it) if they solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is my o(n) time and o(1) solution for this problem

```
int j = 0;
public void sortColors(int[] nums) {
    if(nums.length == 0)
        return;
   for(int i=0; i<=2; ++i){
       j = sort(j, i, nums);
   }
}

int sort(int start, int color, int A[]){
    int k = start;
    for(int i=start; i<A.length; ++i){
        if(A[i] == color){
            int temp = A[k];
            A[k] = A[i];
            A[i] = temp;
            ++k;
        }
    }
    // the last index of the current color
    return k;
}
```